# Enable/ disable button when a div collapse

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have code for collapsing using bootstrap like this :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#foo">Edit</a>

<div id="foo" class="collapse">
some text.
</div>

<button type="button" class="continue">Continue</button>
```

How to make continue button enable when `foo`is collapse out, and dissable when `foo` is collapse in?

Comment: What jquery code you have written for this?

Comment: try this http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), the collapse plugin in bootstrap fires several events that you can hook onto.

The ones we are interested in are `shown.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse`. They will fire when either `foo` is collapsed out or collapsed in respectively.

[Now we just have to hook onto the events.](http://jsfiddle.net/582ofra7/)

```
$('#foo').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.continue').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

$('#foo').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.continue').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js 
Try this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
  simple collapsible
</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse"> This is testing demo div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create it yourself? It's better for experience.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').on('click'){
        $('selected-div').slideToggle(); 
    }
});
```